# Vue performance issue with input type color and v-model

Tags: javascript, performance, vue.js, v-model

I'm setting the **`v-model`** on input type color. The issue is when I change the color, frame drop occurs and application FPS surges from 60 FPS to 3 FPS. Here is the screenshot of the Vue performance graph.

[image: Color Picker]

[image: Performance View]

How do I tackle down this performance issue? I'm not using the Vue single-file components. I just have a Vue on the solo page and using v-model to handle input changes. Here is the color input code,

```html
<div v-if="conf.type === 'color'" class="col-1">
    <input type="color" v-model="conf.default">
</div>
```

What the thing leads to sudden drop of FPS? Is there any solution for this? I'm facing this on chrome version 83.0, didn't test in other browsers yet.

Note: I tried using `@change`, and it's performing well without performance issues. Here is the code

```html
<div v-if="conf.type === 'color'" class="col-1">
    <input type="color" @change="setStyle($event)">
</div>
```

Seems that it's only the issue with using `v-model`. I would have used it but I want the color to be updated in realtime. Here, `@change` listener updates the value after the color input loses focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you are using the color to update parts of your DOM. The color picker can update the v-model value a lot especially if the user is dragging to pick a color. This can be expensive on performance depending on what you are doing with the color. One thing you could try is to throttle how often your color gets updated.

```html
<input type="color" v-model="color">
```

Here I am using lodashes [throttle](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#throttle) method to throttle the color changing every 500 milliseconds.

```js
import throttle from 'lodash/throttle'

{
    watch: {
         color: function () {
             this.throttledColor()
         }
    },
    methods: {
        // update color every 500 milliseconds
        throttledColor: throttle(function () {
            this.conf.default = this.color
        }, 500)
    }

}
```

See this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-scjcbh?file=index.js) to see a comparison of how many times the color is getting updated standard vs throttle.

Comment: You guessed right, I'm updating the UI based on the change of color. I already throttled the color to 100ms to avoid performance lack. As I've said i want the UI should reflect in realtime that's why I'm preferring using `v-model`  over `@change`. Your answer makes sense. throttling to 100ms gives me a near-exact solution to me. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @KiranManiya I'm glad I could help!